# How to adjust new method to provide for situation that id parameter is not present?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, null

For the `new method` below I'm running in the problem that for current_user there is no organization_id if that user directly visits the new path rather than trough a link that is provided (the link passes the id but directly visiting the url there's no id). Without an id there's the error message `Couldn't find Organization with 'id'=`.

```
def new
  if current_user && current_user.admin?
    @organization = Organization.find(params[:organization_id])
    @member = @organization.members.build
  elsif current_member && current_member.admin?
    @member = current_organization.members.build
  else
    flash[:danger] = "Error"
  end
end
```

How can I adjust the `new method` so that when no organization_id is provided there's an error flash and redirect? Within the existing if... line, I tried:

```
if params[:organization_id].nil
  flash[:danger] = "Please select an organization first"
  redirect_to organizations_path
end
```

but this gave the error `undefined method 'nil' for nil:NilClass`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is called [`.nil?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/NilClass.html#method-i-nil-3F), not `.nil`:

```
params[:organization_id].nil?
```